# Margin note on adjacent page

Tags: footnotes, marginpar, marginnote

I was wondering if there was a way to put margin notes (and possible footnotes) on the adjacent page. I want to put together a document that incorporates a large amount of references and "margin definitions". Saving paper is not a concern for this particular document, and thought that it would be nice to do a one sided document for the body of the text, and have margin notes, footnotes and condensed citations on the opposite page.

Any help greatly appreciated...

Comment: It would be better if you give more infos. Why distinguish footnote and marginpar, isn't really that you want a comments page?

Comment: I want something similar to a comments page. The reason I don't consider it a comments page is that I generally consider a comments page as a construct used in the process of creating a document in a collaborative environment. 

You are correct that I did not have to distinguish between footnote and margin par. The reason I did however is that I generally think of a marginpar as little block of text that provides a definition or description that is used in the related text. whereas I generally think of a footnote as being something that points out some omitted detail, assumption, reference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let start with this

**Update:** No need to patch `\@outputbox`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\makeatletter
\newbox\mtbox
\def \@opcol {%
  \if@twocolumn
    \@outputdblcol
  \else
    \@outputpage
    \ifvoid\mtbox\else
      \let\@outputbox\mtbox
      \@outputpage
    \fi
  \fi
  \global \@mparbottom \z@ \global \@textfloatsheight \z@
  \@floatplacement
}
\gdef \@makecol {%
   \ifvoid\footins
     \setbox\@outputbox \box\@cclv
   \else
     \setbox\@outputbox \vbox {%
       \boxmaxdepth \@maxdepth
       \unvbox \@cclv
       }%
   \setbox\mtbox \vbox to\@colht {%
       \color@begingroup
         \normalcolor
         \unvbox \footins
       \color@endgroup
   }%
   \fi
   \let\@elt\relax
   \xdef\@freelist{\@freelist\@midlist}%
   \global \let \@midlist \@empty
   \@combinefloats
   \ifvbox\@kludgeins
     \@makespecialcolbox
   \else
     \setbox\@outputbox \vbox to\@colht {%
       \@texttop
       \dimen@ \dp\@outputbox
       \unvbox \@outputbox
       \vskip -\dimen@
       \@textbottom
       }%
   \fi
   \global \maxdepth \@maxdepth
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
bla\footnote{\lipsum[1-2]}\lipsum[1-2]
bla\footnote{\lipsum[1]}\lipsum[1]
bla\footnote{\lipsum[1]}\lipsum[1-3] 
bla\footnote{\lipsum[1-2]}\lipsum[1]
bla\footnote{\lipsum[1]}\lipsum[1] 
bla\footnote{\lipsum[1]}\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

**Explanation** Normal latex output routine calls commands `\@makecol` and `\@opcol`

command `\@makecol` normally saves the content of page (body text + footnotes) into vbox `\@outputbox` so we change it, now the body text is saved into `\@outputbox` and footnotes text into new box `\mtbox`.

command `\@opcol` call `\@outputpage` that shipout pages. We change it, now we call `\@outputpage` twice, first for the body text and then for the footnotes.

Comment: The space for the footnotes is empty on the pages with text. Is it possible to change that?

Comment: I will try to see. Sorry but i don't have time.