# versonotes not printing

Tags: notes

Following on from my previous question [instructor student version](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/320126/instructor-student-version) I tried using the suggested package `versonotes` answer as given by @Willie Wong.

The following MWE

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{versonotes}
\begin{document}
\chapter{First}
This is just some random text so I can show a versonote.\versonote{This is the versonote referring to the text I just wrote.}
\end{document}
```

produces the following warnings:

> Package versopages Warning: page 1 verso text will be ignored on input line 5.
>   Package versopages Warning: page 1 verso text will be ignored on input line 6.
>   )

I have made multiple passes to get the formatting but why is it being ignored?

I have compiled the `sample.tex` given with the package and it works fine!

Am I missing something incredibly simple?

Comment: Well, if the chapter 'First' is on the first page it will be on the recto page of course (as long there is no other setup), so there is no verso page yet. Try `\tableofcontents\cleardoublepage` before `\chapter{First}` and the warning will vanish, having the verso note on the 2nd page (the 'empty' one after `Contents`) (`\chapter` will appear on the recto page normally, unless `openany' has specified)

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Perfect. It's the subtleties that catch me! Write it up as an answer and I'll accept!

Comment: I've done so...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no `verso` page if the chapter start page is the first one at all and this is usually the recto page, so `\versonote` must fail here.

If there is other content and perhaps an empty (or partially empty) page before (achievable for example with `\cleardoublepage`), a `verso` page is possible and `\versonote` won't complain any longer.